# Problem while running navigation stack for turtlebot

Tags: navigation, turtlebot, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After going through ROS tutorials on navigation stack, I was trying to implement it on Turtlebot with Kinect. I have done the following to get navigation stack up and running:

1. I have created a launch file for pointcloud to laser transformation first (kinect_laser.launch).
2. I am using turtlebot_navigation package for all config yaml costmap files, move_base and amcl.
3. Created a package for publishing odometer data and for setting up /map to /odom link as this can't be static transform publisher.
4. Then I created one launch file with "tf" static transform publisher for /base_link to /camera_link (Kinect), included the above created node in step 3, included amcl and move_base (which has all yaml config files).
5. When I am launching this final created file, everything goes fine as per frames.pdf and rostopic tf tf_echo /map /odom (as per movement of bot, values are changing) but after every topic gets published, it throws following message:

" The sensor at ( , ) is out of map bound. Hence, the costmap can't raytrace it. "

I am not sure what all costmap files I need to update and how shall I decide on the parameters in costmap like footprint, robot_radius etc. so that I don't get this warning. Also, while clicking on 2D Pose Estimate I am not getting laser beam surrounding that point and on clicking 2D Nav Goal , the robot just rotates at the same position without translating to the goal.

Anyone please suggest on this ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59482/problem-while-running-navigation-stack-for-turtlebot./) by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) on ROS Answers with karma: 320 on 2013-03-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) on 2013-04-05**:
Issue is resolved now. Figured out the problem: The transform from /map to /odom is static but /odom to /base_link varies. Hence, edited and made changes to the tf publisher for /odom to /base_link and respective launch files. Also, first tried navigating bot in the environment and saved map then

**Comment by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) on 2013-04-05**:
tried using that map for setting 2D pose estimate and giving 2D Nav goal which then worked as expected and robot can now autonomously navigate through environment. However, I had to include launch file for SLAM that I created for SLAM in navigation launch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Issue is resolved now. Figured out the problem: The transform from /map to /odom is static but /odom to /base_link varies. Hence, edited and made changes to the tf publisher for /odom to /base_link and respective launch files. Also, first tried navigating bot in the environment and saved map then tried using that map for setting 2D pose estimate and giving 2D Nav goal which then worked as expected and robot can now autonomously navigate through environment. However, I had to include launch file for SLAM that I created for SLAM in navigation launch file.

---

Originally posted by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) with karma: 320 on 2013-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0